# Windbg on release mode doesn't work

Tags: c++, debugging, mfc, windbg

I compiled this small MFC application which throws an exception when I click a CButton using VS2010.

It was on **release mode** and created pdb files and map files.

Then I used these commands, symfix and sympath+ to let the debugger know where the symbols are. After .reload I entered g, clicked the exception button, and it crashed as expected but the problem here is when I do kb, it doesn't show full call stack, while it successfully shows its call stack pointing where the exception is coming from when I compile this app on **debug mode**.

I believe that it should be an easy problem about compile options but I obviously am missing things.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Release mode, code optimization is on and so the compiler rearranges your code and throws out some of it. This is probably the reason why you don't see what you expect to see. Try disabling optimization by going to Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Optimization -> Optimization.

Comment: Thanks. It works that way. But then the release mode becomes just the same as debug mode without any optimization.

Comment: Well, not exactly the same, but for optimizations. Since the exception also occurs in debug mode, use that for debugging. Once it is corrected, the exception should also go away in Release mode.

Comment: Note that you can change the optimization setting on a per-project or per-file basis, and (with `#pragma`) even on a per-line basis. Such mixing is not unusual at all: you commonly load Windows DLLs in your process without caring about their optimization level.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure your pdbs have the full symbols, so you need to specify in the pdb settings not to strip the private symbols, this will ensure you that you will get the full call stacks, optmization settings should not have caused your problem.

Think about it how come you can get the MicroSoft pdbs from the symbol server to work fine when you are debugging Windows code if the windows code is not optimized??

See this for more information on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Under your project settings: Configuration Properties > Linker > Debugging make sure that 'Strip Private Symbols' is empty.

You can confirm whether the pdbs match your code by entering:

```
!chksym mydll
```

or the undocumented command which does the same thing:

```
!itoldyouso mydll
```